# Handling out of memory exception when output of processElement is fat

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow

While I am using dataflow, I need to make some string rows which have user id list separated by comma. And then write results in GCS.
Unfortunately, during the processElement of DoFn, each row has too many users which results in java.lang.OutOfMemoryError.
Is there any way to avoid OutOfMemory exception and successfully write fat rows for each line in GCS with text file?
My source code is like below.

```
PCollection<KV<String, String>> rows = someData
    .apply(Combine.<String, String>perKey(new CombineUserIds()));

public static class CombineUserIds implements SerializableFunction<Iterable<String>, String> {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 0;

  @Override
  public String apply(Iterable<String> userIdList) {
    return Joiner.on(",").join(userIdList);
  }
}
```

Here, `someData` in the source code is `PCollection<KV<String, String>>` type whose key is group_id and value is user_id.
And following is entire error message
`(b997767fac436e5c): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3332) at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(AbstractStringBuilder.java:137) at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:121) at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:421) at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:136) at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:76) at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:457) at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:166) at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:76) at com.google.common.base.Joiner.appendTo(Joiner.java:111) at com.google.common.base.Joiner.appendTo(Joiner.java:152) at com.google.common.base.Joiner.join(Joiner.java:193) at com.google.common.base.Joiner.join(Joiner.java:183) at com.moloco.dataflow.ml.adhoc.GenerateMLUserProfileSet$CombineUserIds.apply(GenerateMLUserProfileSet.java:189) at com.moloco.dataflow.ml.adhoc.GenerateMLUserProfileSet$CombineUserIds.apply(GenerateMLUserProfileSet.java:184) at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.transforms.Combine$IterableCombineFn.mergeToSingleton(Combine.java:1613) at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.transforms.Combine$IterableCombineFn.mergeAccumulators(Combine.java:1591) at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.transforms.Combine$IterableCombineFn.mergeAccumulators(Combine.java:1536) at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.transforms.Combine$CombineFn$2.mergeAccumulators(Combine.java:489) at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFnFactory$MergingKeyedCombineFn.extractOutput(GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFnFactory.java:249) at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFnFactory$MergingKeyedCombineFn.extractOutput(GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFnFactory.java:216) at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.GroupAlsoByWindowsAndCombineDoFn$KeyedCombineFnRunner.extractOutput(GroupAlsoByWindowsAndCombineDoFn.java:243) at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.GroupAlsoByWindowsAndCombineDoFn.closeWindow(GroupAlsoByWindowsAndCombineDoFn.java:206) at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.GroupAlsoByWindowsAndCombineDoFn.processElement(GroupAlsoByWindowsAndCombineDoFn.java:192) at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.SimpleDoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:49) at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunnerBase.processElement(DoFnRunnerBase.java:138) at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.SimpleParDoFn.processElement(SimpleParDoFn.java:190) at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.ForwardingParDoFn.processElement(ForwardingParDoFn.java:42) at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorkerLoggingParDoFn.processElement(DataflowWorkerLoggingParDoFn.java:47) at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:53) at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:52) at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.runReadLoop(ReadOperation.java:226)`

Comment: Are you running your pipeline locally, or in Google cloud?

Comment: Hi @polleyg, I am running on Google cloud. And I also tried with n1-himem-32 workertype as well. But it failed with out of memory exception.

Answer (score -2):

From Oracle [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/memleaks002.html),

**Exception in thread thread_name: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space**

> **Cause**: The detail message Java heap space indicates object could not
>   be allocated in the Java heap. This error does not necessarily imply a
>   memory leak. The problem can be as simple as a configuration issue,
>   where the specified heap size (or the default size, if it is not
>   specified) is insufficient for the application.

**Solution1:** Increase JVM heap size as below.

You could specify per project how much heap space your project wants

Following is for Eclipse :

Right mouse click on

```
Run As - Run Configuration - Arguments - Vm Arguments,
```

then add this

```
-Xmx1024
```

or

```
-Xmx2048m
```

**Solution2 (Only after tried Solution1 ):**

Again from Oracle [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/memleaks004.html#CIHCDBJB),

> **3.4.3 Monitor the Objects Pending Finalization** 
>   When the OutOfMemoryError exception is thrown with the "Java heap space" > detail
>   message, the cause can be excessive use of finalizers. To diagnose
>   this, you have several options for monitoring the number of objects
>   that are **pending finalization**:
>
> The [JConsole](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/tooldescr009.html#BABDCICF) management tool can be used to **monitor** the number of
>   objects that are pending finalization. This tool reports the pending
>   finalization count in the memory statistics on the Summary tab pane.
>   The count is approximate, but it can be used to characterize an
>   application and understand if it relies a lot on finalization.
>
> On Oracle Solaris and Linux operating systems, the jmap utility can be
>   used with the -finalizerinfo option to print information about objects
>   awaiting finalization.
>
> An application can report the approximate number of objects pending
>   finalization using the getObjectPendingFinalizationCount method of the
>   java.lang.management.MemoryMXBean class. Links to the API
>   documentation and example code can be found in [Custom Diagnostic
>   Tools](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/tooldescr021.html#BABEDEBD). The example code can easily be extended to include the
>   reporting of the pending finalization count.

Comment: Thank you @Sundararaj Govindasamy for kind answer. However, I am not using eclipse for running dataflow job and each row's memory may exceed the memory you give me in your suggestion. I think the solution of my question should be more related to dataflow itself rather than java. Thank you very much anyway.

Comment: @Kyuntae, whether you are using eclipse or not, underlying problem is Java related only. What is the size of userIdList? and how many UserIdLists you are joining? What are the total no of objects in total in this entire Joiner? Say for example, if this entire joiner is trying to join 10000 objects, it is trying to hold those 10000 objects in Java Heap, but there is no memory available to hold those. Either you need to allocate more memory to Java Heap OR you may write code which is using memory effectively, such as clearing objects from memory when that object has no reference.Hope this helps

Comment: Hi @Sundararaj Govindasamy, As far as I know, dataflow does not allow to set heap size using -Xmx flag(Refer to [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30795924/cloud-dataflow-increase-jvm-xmx-value) to avoid negatively impacting the shuffler. In my case, each row's size is too big to be loaded in memory. (2 billion userIds and each userId's size is about 40~50bytes)

Comment: I never worked in dataflow, so i can't help you there. Why you are trying to load all at once? I don't think it is a good idea.

Comment: Because I gotta meet the data format which other team requested. Thank you for helping me @Sundararaj

Comment: Always welcome @Kyuntae, you can upvote this answer, if you feel it is useful, in some way.